# Objective C: How to read from saved files?

Tags: objective-c

Bellow i have some code that saves a .mp4 file. The file is saved within the documents directory of my app folder. However i now want to retrieve the video files that have been saved within the documents directory and display on screen with a thumbnail and the title of the video to then allow the user to select a individual video to watch. The playing of the video should be carried out by `MPMoviePlayerController`.

**Code to save file:**

```
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%f.mp4", NSHomeDirectory(),[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];

    [videoData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    [videoData release];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your problem?  (StackOverflow is not a place to get things coded for you.)

Comment: This place is not here to give u ready made stuff- You are supposed to ask relevant issue after you try some solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using NSURLs

```
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f.mp4",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = NSURL *URLForDirectory = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory: NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:fileName relativeToURL:URLForDirectory];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the path to the file (named e.g. example.mp4) in the documents directory:

```
NSArray *paths = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
NSURL *documentsURL = [paths lastObject];
NSURL *filePathURL = [documentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"example.mp4"];
```

Comment: You do know that it's recommended to use NSURLs instead of string based file paths nowadays, don't you?

Comment: @Abizern Do you have a good citation for your statement?

Comment: @Abizern Sure do, since they are faster and all that. However, since I assumed that fine Mr. user2534692 is not a very experienced programmer I thought it better not to confuse him.

Comment: @rmaddy Have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html in the Overview section, 3rd paragraph.

Comment: @rmaddy NSURL paths are suppose to be somewhat faster than using NSString paths. OR so I've heard. I would say that it really doesn't make a difference in this "one time access case" though.

Comment: @Filip You do the questioner no favours by shielding him/her from modern programming.

Comment: @Abizern You are correct! Edited my answer based on your comments!

Comment: @Filip Based on the recommendation, it would be better to replace the call to `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` with a call to `URLsForDirectory:inDomains:` and get back an array of `NSURL` objects instead of an array of `NSString` objects.